# Alternatives to GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking for an alternative to use to remove duplicates for an alias column. I know that I can't use the GROUP BY function on an alias, but I don't know how to get rid of the duplicates in that column.

```
SELECT        
(select Sites.SiteZipCode 
FROM Sites 
WHERE Sites.SiteName = TransportationPolicies.DestinationSite) AS DESTZIP1,
(SELECT        Sites.SiteZipCode
FROM Sites 
WHERE Sites.SiteName = TransportationPolicies.SOURCESite) AS SOURCESITE1,
((select Sites.SiteZipCode FROM Sites WHERE Sites.SiteName = TransportationPolicies.DestinationSite) + '_' + (SELECT  Sites.SiteZipCode FROM Sites WHERE Sites.SiteName = TransportationPolicies.SOURCESite)) 
AS CONCZIP, TransportationPolicies.SourceSite, TransportationPolicies.DestinationSite
FROM TransportationPolicies
GROUP BY CONCZIP
```

Comment: A little formatting goes a long way to help you and your reader understand the query  you attempted. Before we even consider grouping, what are you trying to achieve? You are selecting rows from TransportationPolicies but you group (without any aggregate) by a value from a different table. So you desire (apparently) one row per zip code - what values do you want to see for the other columns / expressions? I think a join will work "better" than a correlated subquery here - but uncertain about the rest.

Answer (score 0):

In-line sub-queries are very rarely necessary. You just need two joins to `Sites` to retrieve the columns you need. In addition to Smor's observations about formatting, table aliases will go a long way toward uncomplicating your code as well.

This is untested, as we have no data to work with, but I believe should return the results you're looking for. Depending on your data, you may need `LEFT JOIN` instead.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  dest.SiteZipCode AS DESTZIP1,
  src.SiteZipCode AS SOURCESITE1,
  dest.SiteZipCode + '_' + src.SiteZipCode AS CONCZIP, 
  tpol.SourceSite, 
  tpol.DestinationSite
FROM 
  TransportationPolicies AS tpol
JOIN
  Sites as dest
    ON dest.SiteName = tpol.DestinationSite
JOIN
  Sites as src
    ON src.SiteName = tpol.SOURCESite;
```

Answer (score -1):

Not an answer - just a demonstration of how formatting / whitespace increase the ability to read and understand your query

```
SELECT        
   (select Sites.SiteZipCode FROM Sites 
    WHERE Sites.SiteName = TransportationPolicies.DestinationSite) AS DESTZIP1,

   (SELECT Sites.SiteZipCode FROM Sites 
    WHERE Sites.SiteName = TransportationPolicies.SOURCESite) AS SOURCESITE1,

   ((select Sites.SiteZipCode FROM Sites WHERE Sites.SiteName = TransportationPolicies.DestinationSite) 
   + '_' 
   + (SELECT  Sites.SiteZipCode FROM Sites WHERE Sites.SiteName = TransportationPolicies.SOURCESite)) 
   AS CONCZIP, 

   TransportationPolicies.SourceSite, 
   TransportationPolicies.DestinationSite
FROM TransportationPolicies
GROUP BY CONCZIP
ORDER BY CONCZIP;
```